# Calling php web service from net application

Tags: c#, php, web-services, webforms

Good day dear friends. I'm tying to call PHP web service, created with **SoapServer** from net winform application. 
PHP method is recieving xml string as parameter and returning json encoded array:

```
    function getPolicy($contentsXml) {
        if ($everyting->isOK) {
            $resultArr = createResultArray();
        }else{
            // Process errors
        }
        $result = json_encode($resultArr);
        return $result;
    }
```

This is wsdl included in php web service i'm using to add **web reference** to visual studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="XmlImportClaimWSDL"
            targetNamespace="http://172.16.6.130/online/my.wsdl"
            xmlns:tns="http://172.16.6.130/online/my.wsdl"
            xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
            xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
            xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" >
         <element name="getPolicy">
             <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentsXml" type="xsd:string" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
          </element>
          <element name="getPolicyResponse">
             <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentsXml" type="xsd:json" />
                </sequence>
             </complexType>
         </element>
    </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getPolicyRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="requestParam" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getPolicyResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="responseParam" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ServerClaimSoapType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPolicy">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getPolicyRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getPolicyResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ServerClaimSoapBinding" type="tns:ServerClaimSoapType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPolicy">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://php-server-address/"/>
     <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output>
       <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ServerClaim">
    <wsdl:port name="ServerClaimSoap" binding="tns:ServerClaimSoapBinding">
      <soap:address  location="http://php-server-address/phpSoapService.php" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As I can see from fiddler, PHP receives parameter and sends back correct json object, but in net code result is always null. Net code is:

```
PhpSoapObject client = new PhpSoapObject();
var result = client.getPolicy(PredifenedXmlString);
```

So the **result** variable is always null; My guess is wsdl binding. I've searched a lot about this situation. I've realized that using php web service with net framework without **nusoap** is very poorly documented. Thanks everyone for reading such a long question.

Answer (score 0):

So after many trials everything is working now. Thanks to Eclipse wsdl editor, relay great tool. php wsdl should be defined as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="XmlImportClaimWSDL"
            targetNamespace="http://172.16.6.130/online/"
            xmlns:tns="http://172.16.6.130/online/"
            xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
            xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
            xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://172.16.6.130/online/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
  <xsd:element name="getPolicy">
             <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentsXml" type="xsd:string" />
                 </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="getPolicyResponse">
             <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getPolicyResult" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getPolicyRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="requestParam" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getPolicyResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="responseParam" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ServerClaimSoapType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPolicy">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getPolicyRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getPolicyResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ServerClaimSoapBinding" type="tns:ServerClaimSoapType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPolicy">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://172.16.6.130/online/getPolicy" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://172.16.6.130/online/"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://172.16.6.130/online/"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ServerClaim">
    <wsdl:port name="ServerClaimSoap" binding="tns:ServerClaimSoapBinding">
      <soap:address  location="http://172.16.6.130/phpSoapService.php" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The main problem was incorect **schema namespace** and ***binding body namespace missing***. I hope this will help someone.
P.S. Stackoverflow is the best place to search for your problem.